# Don't optimize only one import

Tags: webstorm

In WebStorm using Google Maps you have too import `@types/googlemaps`.
I'm doing it with statement: `import {} from '@types/googlemaps';`

Problem is that whenever I reformat code that line is deleted.

I want WebStorm to optimize my imports but how to make him leave that one?

Comment: Did you save the file correctly as typescript?

Comment: there is a checkbox that will allow you to disable the import optimization through the reformat code action on the directory.

Comment: @UlugToprak I found only `show notification after optimize import action`

Comment: strange... what options do you see when you `Ctrl+Alt-L`? there should be a check box for remove unused imports

Comment: I have no options - no window

Comment: I have it - shift+alt+ctrl+L - thanks

Comment: You may try surrounding that particular line with "no reformat" comments -- might help: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/reformatting-source-code.html?search=reformat#formatter_options